# Can I run "live" Ubuntu from a USB drive?

Tags: 12.04, live-usb

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on a USB drive via the Universal USB Installer, but it only gives me the option to install Ubuntu, not "try" Ubuntu. Is this not possible? The problem is, I don't have access to a CD burner.

Comment: Why didn't you use unetbootin.. and it *should* have the option to Try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many people have problems with Universal USB Installer.

Try UNetbootin, it runs in Windows, or better yet try usb-creator, (Startup disk creator), the Live USB installer that comes with the Live CD.

Usb-creator.exe, (for Windows), can be extracted from iso's prior to 12.04.